# Default member values best practice

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, header-files, default-value

Is it good practice when writing C++11 code to set default values for class members in the header file of the class?

Or is it better to do this in the constructor of the class?

EDIT:

I mean:

**foo.h**:

```
#include <string>

using std::string;

class Foo{
    private:
        string greet = "hello";
    public:
        Foo();
};
```

VS

**foo.cpp** (of course with the necessary header file, but without the in-class initialization):

```
Foo::Foo(){
    greet = "hello";
}
```

Which one is better and why?

Comment: What do you mean in the header file? C++11 in-class member initialization? A code sample of both cases would help illustrate.

Comment: @chris updated with code samples.

Comment: Those two samples do different things, so certainly the first one is better. Search for _member initialization list_

Comment: using clauses in header should be avoided

Comment: A bit late, I know – you should use constructors initialisation list: `Foo::Foo() : greet("hello") { }` – this avoids default initialisation + assignment in favour of direct initialisation by value. For complex types, this can make a significant difference, more important, though: Some types (references, constant members, non-default constructible ones) *only* can be initialised that way (in the constructor, apart from assigning a default).

Comment: Explanation from "Inside the C++ Object Model" by Stanley B. Lippman. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183155/initializer-list-vs-constructor-assignment-vs-variable-defining

Answer (score 128, accepted):

If a class member is always initialized with the same initial value, then you should make the initializer inline, so as to avoid duplication. If the initial value depends on the constructor, then put it in the constructor initializer list. (And never use assignment in the way you did.)

Example:

```
class Foo
{
    bool done = false;   // always start like this
    int qty;
    Bar * p;

public:
    Foo()                        : qty(0),              p(nullptr)    { }
    Foo(int q, Bar * bp)         : qty(q),              p(bp)         { }
    explicit Foo(char const * s) : qty(std::strlen(s)), p(new Bar(s)) { }

    // ...
};
```

In this hypothetical example, the member `done` is always required to start as `false`, so it's best to write the initializer inline. The other two members, `qty` and `p`, can be initialized differently in each of three different constructors, so they are initialized inside the constructors' initializer lists.

<sub>A curiosum: Note that providing an inline initializer prevents your class from having a *trivial default constructor*.</sub>

Comment: You can also use constructor delegation to avoid redundancies.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: That's very true, though I think that feature solves a somewhat orthogonal problem.

Comment: "never use assignment in the way you did." I think explaining why one should never do this would be a good addition to your answer.

Comment: @cp.engr: Because you should generally initialize, not reassign.

Comment: @KerrekSB What's the difference between assignment that Paul used and the assignment you used? Both assign a member variable to a value.

Comment: @JossieCalderon: I never use assignment :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB On line 3 of your example, done “done = false” count as an assignment?

Answer (score 13):

It depends whether you need to stay compatible with older C++ compilers .When you are not using C++11 you have to initialize most members (all non-static) in the constructor.
Further many people advocate to explicitly initialize every member even if this means explicitly calling the default ctor.
Usually you should place implementation details in a cpp file not in the header file, thus an example would be

```
Example:
//foo.h

class Foo{
public: 
  Foo();
private:
  std::vector<int> vect;
};

//foo.cpp

Foo::Foo():vect(){
}
```

In C++11 you have more choices and in class member initializer will become very handy, especially if you have several cors. Here is a good link for more information: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init

**After Edit:** According to your code you are using C++11. To my knowledge there is only few information on good practice concerning the new possibilities but IMHO In class member initializer are very handy to concentrate initialization in one place, which reduces complexity and typing

Comment: Yeah, I updated my question to better reflect what I meant, I mostly agree with you on "reduces complexity and typing".

Answer (score 5):

Initializing in headers has the main advantages of keeping code more local and easy to understand. It saves also some typing.

The main disadvantage, in my opinion, is the need to include more headers to get access to constructors. Simple forward declaration won't suffice, making compilation take longer.

Comment: "making compilation take longer" I can't say I've ever found myself in a situation where I had any concern over compile times.

Comment: We have come a long way from 2012 in terms of processor speed, but the difference between a 30 seconds recompile or a 30 minute recompile is still something which can make a big difference. The size of the code base is certainly the primary point to look out for.