# Initializer list vs Constructor assignment vs variable defining

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, initializer-list

I'm trying to understand the real difference between the following Classes.

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    :width(500)
    ,height(300){};
    int width;
    int height;
};

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        width = 500;
        height = 300;
    };
    int width;
    int height;
};

class C
{
public:
    int width = 500;
    int height = 300;
};
```

Which one do you think is the best way to initialize `width` and `height` variables in a class?

Should I stick to one way over the others?

Comment: Use A or C. B is an assignment, not an initialization, which is a big difference with non-primitive members and things that can't be assigned to.

Comment: For this class they are all the same; however for more complicated classes (particularly - where the data members are not primitive types) they are different as explained in the linked question

Comment: @M.M This is not a duplicate of the question you brought as it doesn't include something like the `class C`.

Comment: OK. However I vote to close as "primarily opinion-based" as you are asking people's opinions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This excerpt has been taken from "Inside the C++ Object Model" by Stanley B. Lippman.

> You must use the member initialization list in the following cases in
>   order for your program to compile:
>   1. When initializing a reference member
>   2. When initializing a const member
>   3. When invoking a base or member class constructor with a set of arguments
>   4. A few efficiency cases. (Here the program is correct w/o member initialization list)

For points 1-3, member initialization list is a must.
For point 4, it is not compulsory.

For example(point 4), given :

```
class Word {
   String _name;
   int _cnt;
   public:
   // not wrong, just naive ...
   Word() {
      _name = 0;
      _cnt = 0;
   }
};
```

This implementation of the `Word` constructor initializes `_name` once, then overrides the initialization with an assignment, resulting in the creation and the destruction of a temporary `String` object.

A significantly more efficient implementation would have been coded:

```
// preferred implementation
Word::Word : _name( 0 )
{
    _cnt = 0;
}
```

Due to this optimisation, a lot of people prefer member initialization list, as a default approach to write constructors.

```
// some insist on this coding style
Word::Word()
   : _cnt( 0 ), _name( 0 )
   {}
```

A reasonable question to ask at this point is, **what actually happens to the member initialization list**?

The compiler iterates over the initialization list, inserting the initializations in the proper order within the constructor prior to any explicit user code.
For example, the previous `Word` constructor is expanded as follows:

```
// Pseudo C++ Code
Word::Word( /* this pointer goes here */ )
{
   _name.String::String( 0 );
   _cnt = 0;
}
```

> Note : The order in which the list entries are set down is determined
>   by the declaration order of the members within the class declaration,
>   not the order within the initialization list. In this case, `_name` is
>   declared before `_cnt` in `Word` and so is placed first.

So coming back to your question :

`class B` is fine(since you are using primitive datatypes).

`class A` will generate the same code as `class B`

As for `class C`, the default constructor is first called, and then initialization of `width` and `height` would happen. This method should be preferred when there are going to be more than 1 constructor, and for each constructor `width` and `height` need to be defaulted to your desired values.

However, since the advent of C++11, and use of `{}` as uniform initialization, a more recommended approach for writing `class C` would be :

```
class C
{
    public:
    int width {500};
    int height {300};
};
```

Comment: I believe this is a better answer than the linked threads.