# C++ - Is it possible to use both types of constructor in an inherited class or when can I use second code type?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, inherited, inherited-constructors

I have abstract class Father and inherited class Son.
 Father has attributes name and *properties*.
 Son has inherited *name*, *properties* and own *school* attribut.

Father.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Father.h"

class Father {
protected:
    std::string m_name;
    std::vector<std::string> m_properties;

public:
    virtual int calculateSalary() = 0;
};
```

Father.cpp:

```
#include "Father.h"
```

Son.h:

```
class Son: public Father{

    std::string m_school;

    //std::string m_name;  //No need to declare inherited classes again
    //std::vector<std::string> m_properties; //No need to declare inherited classes again


public:
    Son(std::string school, std::string name, std::vector<std::string> properties);
    //Son(std::string school):Father(std::string name, std::vector<std::string> properties);
    int calculateSalary();
};
```

Son.cpp:

```
#include "Son.h"

Son::Son(std::string school, std::string name, std::vector<std::string> properties){
    m_school = school;
    m_name = name;
    m_properties = properties;
}

int Son::calculateSalary() {
    // Implement the calculateSalary function for Son
    return 0; // Placeholder return value
}
```

This is code without any error. I would like to ask about constructor in Son.cpp. I have this code here in this time:

```
Son::Son(std::string school, std::string name, std::vector<std::string> properties){
    m_school = school;
    m_name = name;
    m_properties = properties;
}
```

but I know second code type which would looks like this:

```
Son::Son(std::string school, std::string name, std::vector<std::string> properties)
        : Father(name, properties), m_school(school) {}
```

in this example... I would like to ask when I will use the code which I have in Son.cpp in this time and when I would use the second code type which I mentioned?
**EDIT**:
I am able to use second type of code in case class Father.cpp is implemented:

```
Father::Father(std::string name, std::vector<std::string> properties)
```

but I talked about abstract class (which not have implementation). So I am not able to use second type of code. So is the first one correct?
Thank you for reply

Comment: Use the second code type, which is idiomatic C++.  The first code type looks like someone who learned Java is trying to program in (non-idiomatic) C++.

Comment: [Why should I prefer to use member initializer lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initializer-lists) and [Initializer list vs Constructor assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183155/initializer-list-vs-constructor-assignment-vs-variable-defining)

Comment: The important thing one of them is **initialization** while the other one is **assignment**. They are different things in c++. I would recommend a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that explains this.